# Save multiple async contexts with core data, data missing

Tags: swift, asynchronous, core-data

When the app starts, I want to update my current database. Sometimes not all the data gets saved and some data is missing.

I am doing the save with this function:

```
func save1() {
        let group = DispatchGroup()

        for a in save.oldVersion.defaExchangesEinzeln {
            if save.checkForVersionExchange(exchange: a.key) {
                group.enter()
                save.saveVersionExchanges(exchange: a.key)
                save.storeContainer.performBackgroundTask{ context in
                    self.save.saveDefAExchange(managedContext: context, exchange: a.key)
                    try? context.save()
                    group.leave()
                }
            }
        }
        for b in save.oldVersion.fdefCoinstBtc {
            if save.checkForVersionFdefCoinsTBTC(exchange: b.key) {
                save.saveVersionFdefCoinsTBTC(exchange: b.key)
            }
        }

        for c in save.oldVersion.fdefCoinstUsd {
            if save.checkForVersionFdefCoinsTUSD(exchange: c.key) {
                save.saveVersionFdefCoinsTUSD(exchange: c.key)
            }
        }

        if save.checkForCoinNamesExall() || save.checkForVersionIconsExall() || save.checkForVersionFdefCoinsTarrExall() {
            save.saveVersionOthers()
        }

        if save.checkForCoinNamesExall() {
            group.enter()
            storeContainer?.performBackgroundTask{ context in
                self.save.saveCoinNames(managedContext: context)
                do {
                    try context.save()
                } catch let error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
                group.leave()
            }
        }
        if save.checkForVersionIconsExall() {
            group.enter()
            storeContainer?.performBackgroundTask { context in
                self.save.saveIcons(managedContext: context)
                do {
                    try context.save()
                } catch let error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
                group.leave()
            }
        }

        if save.checkForVersionFdefCoinsTarrExall() {
            group.enter()
            storeContainer?.performBackgroundTask { context in
                self.save.saveGroups(context)
                do {
                    try context.save()
                } catch let error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
                group.leave()
            }
        }
        group.notify(queue: .main) {
            print("Update complete 1")
            self.delegateWebsocket?.startWebsocket()
        }
    }
```

I can imagine that due to the async call the contexts somehow conflict with each other.
Why does it happen? What can I do to improve the code?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `performBackgroundTask` can be incredibly convenient but it has a sharp edge that's not always apparent at first. Every time you call `performBackgroundTask`, a new context is created, and the block you pass in executes on that context's private queue. The block is executed asynchronously.

The upshot is that if you call `performBackgroundTask` repeatedly in a loop, as you are, there's no guarantee that the blocks will be synchronized relative to each other. That can be a problem.

There are a couple of approaches you could take to deal with this. I'm not sure I'm following all of your code so I'm not sure which might be best. Alternatives include:

- Wrap all of the code in a single `performBackgroundTask` instead of creating a bunch of background tasks. Or possibly just reduce the number of tasks by putting `performBackgroundTask` *outside* your initial loop instead of *inside*.
- Drop `performBackgroundTask`. Instead, create a single background context and use that. Get a new context using `newBackgroundContext()` and keep it around. Then replace your background tasks above with `perform` or `performAndWait` calls on that context.

Comment: Thanks, I wrapped all the code in a single performBackgroundTask.